# Subspace of $L^p(X,\Sigma,\lambda)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Consider $R$-valued functions in $L^p(X,\Sigma,\lambda)$, where $X=X^1\times X^2$, $\Sigma=\Sigma^1\times \Sigma^2$ and $\lambda=\lambda^1\times \lambda^2$

For given $i$, does the subsapce

$M=\{f\in L^p(X ,\Sigma,\lambda): f(\cdot,x^{-i})=f(\cdot,\tilde{x}^{-i}), \forall x,\tilde{x}\in X \}$ has the same property as $L^p(X^i ,\Sigma^i,\lambda^i)$?

(i) Is $M$ complete?

(ii) $\{ f\in M| f=\sum_{\alpha_{n}} \chi_{E^i\times T^{-i}}, E^i\in \Sigma^i\}$ is dense in $M$?

(iii) If $M^1\subset M$ is convex and compact and $g\notin M^1$, then there exists $f\in M$ such that $\langle f,g \rangle>\sup_{f'\in M^1}  \langle f',g \rangle$?

Thanks.